# Is there a way to loop a query using a distinct list of values with the way I have written this?

Tags: sql-server

I have written a query that I currently have hardcoded to filter by department. This entire query works the way I want it and I could copy/paste this query dozens of times and write all results to a temp table but I would like a simpler and more dynamic solution. Is there some way I can loop by the distinct results of FullDepartmentFacilityName from my Forecast table? I have a few other areas in this code that are also hard coded that need to be the same value.

'ABC.ALLXYZ' is what I have to hard code

====================================================

```
SELECT *
FROM 
[clc].[ForecastTable]
WHERE 
FullDepartmentFacilityName = 'ABC.ALLXYZ'
and
DateColumn = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
and
(
(ROUND (PopCountForecast, 0) > (SELECT MAX(ACT.PopCountActual) 
FROM 
clc.ActualTable ACT 
JOIN [dim].[DepartmentTable] DTD 
    ON DTD.DeptID = ACT.DeptId 
JOIN [dim].[FacilityTable] FD 
    ON FD.FclID = ACT.FclID 
WHERE 
ACT.DateColumn >= DATEADD(DAY, -28, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) 
and DATEPART(WEEKDAY, ACT.DateColumn) = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) 
and CONCAT(FD.FclName,'.All',DTD.DeptName) = 'ABC.ALLXYZ'))
or
(ROUND (PopCountForecast, 0) < (SELECT MIN(ACT.PopCountActual) 
FROM 
clc.ActualTable ACT 
JOIN [dim].[DepartmentTable] DTD 
    ON DTD.DeptID = ACT.DeptID 
JOIN [dim].[FacilityTable] FD 
    ON FD.FclID = ACT.FclID 
WHERE 
ACT.DateColumn >= DATEADD(DAY, -28, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) 
and DATEPART(WEEKDAY, ACT.DateColumn) = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) 
and CONCAT(FD.FclName,'.All',DTD.DeptName) = 'ABC.ALLXYZ'))
)

Table Structure
clc.ForecastTable - this is the main table for my query. this table has one column with a concatenated facility/department name I am calling FullDepartmentFacilityName. This table has forecasted Population Counts by facility/department key by day.
Example:
FullDepartmentFacilityName     PopCountForecast    Date
ABC.ALLAAA                     10                  7/16/19
ABC.ALLBBB                     5                   7/16/19
ABC.ALLCCC                     8                   7/16/19
BCA.ALLAAA                     9                   7/16/19
BCA.ALLBBB                     4                   7/16/19
BCA.ALLCCC                     9                   7/16/19

"dim.DepartmentTable" - this has all department IDs and their corresponding names
"dim.FacilityTable" - this has all facility IDs and their corresponding names
"clc.ActualTable" - this table contains real data and has a facility column and department column but not a concatenated facility/department column. This is why I created one in my query.
```

Comment: @camba1 I have reworked my redacted query for accuracy. Could you rework your solution based on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `CROSS APPLY`?  You don't give the table structure, so I can only guess what the table structure.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT FullDepartmentFacilityName 
    FROM Forecast
) d
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT *
    FROM [clc].[ForecastTable]
    WHERE FullDepartmentFacilityName = d.FullDepartmentFacilityName
        and DateColumn = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
        and (
            (ROUND (PopCountForecast, 0) > (
                SELECT MAX(ACT.PopCountActual) 
                FROM clc.ActualTable ACT 
                JOIN [dim].[DepartmentTable] DTD ON DTD.DeptID = ACT.DeptId 
                JOIN [dim].[FacilityTable] FD ON FD.FclID = ACT.FclID 
                WHERE ACT.DateColumn >= DATEADD(DAY, -28, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) 
                    and DATEPART(WEEKDAY, ACT.DateColumn) = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) 
                    and CONCAT(FD.FclName,'.All',DTD.DeptName) = 'ABC.ALLXYZ')
        ) or (
            ROUND (PopCountForecast, 0) < (
                SELECT MIN(ACT.PopCountActual) 
                FROM clc.ActualTable ACT 
                JOIN [dim].[DepartmentTable] DTD ON DTD.DeptID = ACT.DeptID 
                JOIN [dim].[FacilityTable] FD ON FD.FclID = ACT.FclID 
                WHERE ACT.DateColumn >= DATEADD(DAY, -28, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) 
                    and DATEPART(WEEKDAY, ACT.DateColumn) = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) 
                    and CONCAT(FD.FclName,'.All',DTD.DeptName) = 'ABC.ALLXYZ')
        )
    )
) c
```

Comment: I will try this. Note I have updated to include the table structure in my post (below the query)

Comment: I replace 'ABC.ALLXYZ' with d.FullDepartmentFacilityName. Presumably this should make the MAX and MIN functions dynamic like the cross apply is supposed to. The query works, I have not validated the data that it works as it should. What are your thoughts?